# Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl chapter 9.2.2 errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and I'm stuck in chapter 9.2.2 "Requiring the Right User", when I add the 2nd user archer to the users.yml file and add the other code to the user_controller_test.rb and the users_controller.rb, the run bundle exec rake test, I get 30 errors stating that:

```
ERROR["test_layout_links", SiteLayoutTest, 0.019046]
 test_layout_links#SiteLayoutTest (0.02s)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:         ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: table users has no column named archer: INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "email", "password_digest", "archer", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('Michael Example', 'michael@example.com', '$2a$04$kDHpg7Zah2wc3X.YbWs5E.pytz8byEkUYo6O7uyPCftblGq3BEogW', '---
        name: Sterling Archer
        email: duchess@example.gov
        password_digest:
```

**users.yml code**

```
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>


  archer:
    name: Sterling Archer
    email: duchess@example.gov
    password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

**users_controller_test.rb code**

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def setup
    @user       = users(:michael)
    @other_user = users(:archer)
  end  

  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should redirect edit when not logged in" do
    get :edit, id: @user
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect update when not logged in" do
    patch :update, id: @user, user: { name: @user.name, email: @user.email }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect edit when logged in as wrong user" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    get :edit, id: @user
    assert flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end

  test "should redirect update when logged in as wrong user" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    patch :update, id: @user, user: { name: @user.name, email: @user.email }
    assert flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end
end
```

**user_controller.rb code**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
        log_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample Application of the Great Bakerboi!"
        redirect_to @user
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end

    def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
          flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
          redirect_to @user
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
      end

    private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end


# Before filters

# Confirms a logged-in user.
def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
end  
end
```

## Confirms the correct user.

```
def correct_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user
end
```

end

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have inadvertently indented the definition of `:archer` in `users.yml`.

Comment: lol, much easier to spot with the posts formatting tidied up :-) +1

Comment: Yeah although I wasn't aware that YAML was whitespace sensitive myself so as is often the case a good learning experience.  I was half into including a whole rspec/capybara/factorygirl apologetic as well (down with opaque fixtures!) but thought learning should be bite sized if possible.  Thanks for the upvote!

Comment: OMG, i have literally spent hours upon hours this past week trying to figure out what was the problems and it was the indentation of the :archer def, lol.  now I what to look for, didn't think to look for indentation, thanks a lot guys, really appreciate your time.